# LEFT Join query issues with

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having some issues getting the following query to work - in all cases I only seem to get a small subset of users back rather than the entire list.
I have the following two tables:

```
Users:

 - UserId
 - email

Updates:

 - UserId 
 - Status
 - LastUpdated
```

What I want to be returned is a list of all users (from Users), their status if it was updated today (based on LastUpdated field) otherwise BLANK or NULL if it wasn't updated today.

I've got as far as this:

```
SELECT users.userid, 
       updates.status 
FROM   users 
       LEFT JOIN updates 
              ON users.userid = updates.userid 
WHERE  Date(lastupdated) = Date(Now())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement to only get `updates.status` if the date is today:

```
SELECT users.userId, 
    CASE WHEN DATE(LastUpdated) = DATE(NOW()) THEN updates.status ELSE NULL END AS status
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN updates ON users.userId=updates.userId
```

Or, better yet, if you don't need anything else from the `updates` row just do:

```
SELECT users.userId, updates.status
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN updates ON users.userId=updates.userId
    AND DATE(LastUpdated) = DATE(NOW())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT    users.userId, updates.status
FROM      users
LEFT JOIN updates
  ON      updates.userId = users.userId
    AND   DATE(updates.LastUpdated) = DATE(NOW())
```

Put your condition within the join, otherwise it's forcing every join to be interrogated. Alternatively, you can check for `LastUpdated` to be `NULL` I believe (since the LEFT join will only include located information).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   SELECT users.userId, case when  DATE(LastUpdated) = DATE(NOW())
 updates.status else null end as status
     FROM users 
LEFT JOIN updates ON users.userId=updates.userIdd
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after is the left outer join to return all users and not only the one that have updates today. That should be something like this:

```
SELECT users.userid, updates.lastupdated
  FROM users
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM updates WHERE DATE(lastupdated) = DATE(NOW())
    ) updates ON users.userid = updates.userid
```